# xPath expression: Getting elements even if they don't exist

Tags: java, xml, xpath, htmlcleaner

I have this xPath expression that I'm putting into htmlCleaner:

```
 //table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/a/img
```

Now, my issue is that it changes, and some times the /a/img element is not present. So I would like an expression that gets all elements

```
//table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/a/img
```

when /a/img is present, and

```
//table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]
```

when /a/img is not present.

Does anyone hav any idea how to do this? I found in another question something that looks like it might help me

```
descendant-or-self::*[self::body or self::span/parent::body]
```

but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the union of two mutually exclusive expressions (notice the `|` union operator):

```
//table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/a/img|
//table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2][not(a/img)]
```

When the first expression returns nodes, the second one will not (and the other way around), which means you'll always get just the required nodes.

From your comments on @Dimitre's answer, I see that HTMLCleaner doesn't fully support XPath 1.0. You don't really need it to. You just need HTMLCleaner to parse input that isn't well-formed. Once it has done that job, convert its output into a standard `org.w3c.dom.Document` and treat it as XML.

Here's a conversion example:

```java
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean("<html><div><p>test");
Document doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);
```

From here on out, just use JAXP with whatever implementation you want:

```java
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/html/body/div/p[not(child::*)]", 
                       doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't confirm that this worked or not since I am no longer working on this (the rest of the program works and I was told to move on to other things). I will come back and add this when I have time. Till then, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
 (//table[@class='StandardTable']
     /tbody/tr)
         [position()>1]
                   /td[2]
                       [not(a/img)] 

|

 (//table[@class='StandardTable']
     /tbody/tr)
         [position()>1]
                   /td[2]
                      /a/img
```

**In general, if we want to select one node-set (`$ns1`) when some condition `$cond` is true and to select another node-set (`$ns2`) otherwise, this can be specified with the following single XPath expression**:

```
$ns1[$cond] | $ns2[not($cond)]
```

**In this particular case, `ns1` is**:

```
 (//table[@class='StandardTable']
     /tbody/tr)
         [position()>1]
                   /td[2]
                      /a/img
```

**and `ns2` is**:

```
 (//table[@class='StandardTable']
     /tbody/tr)
         [position()>1]
                   /td[2]
```

**And `$cond` is**:

```
boolean( (//table[@class='StandardTable']
         /tbody/tr)
             [position()>1]
                       /td[2]
                          /a/img
        )
```

Comment: It keeps giving me an XPatherexception: **Unknown Function not**

Comment: @Nacht: The "it" isn't a compliant XPath implementation. `not()` is a standard XPath function: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-not

Comment: Yeah, just found out that htmlCleaner doesn't do Boolean off the bat, you have to call in another function called "evaluateFunction". And, as always with htmlCleaner, no doc on it. -_-

Comment: @Nacht: then, you need just to substitute `not()` from my solution with whatever htmlCleaner accepts. Please, let me know if this final solution works for you.

Comment: @Nacht - Better yet, just convert HTMLCleaner's output to a W3C `Document` and treat it as though it were XML from the beginning. See my updated answer. Also, +1 for Dimitre beating me to the XPath solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly and it may not even work, but the principle should:

```
//table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2][exists( /a/img )]/a/img | //table[@class='StandardTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2][not( exists( /a/img ) )]
```